# Handling state for a dynamic list of functional components that need to set their own state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I'm creating a little RPG in React.

Currently, I have a player with a useWalk hook which they pass their position to, and the hook handles changing their position as they move around.

```
export const Player: React.FC<PlayerProps> = ({ skin, positionIsWalkable}) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<Position2D>({x: 8, y: 8});
  const { direction, walk } = useWalk(positionIsWalkable, position, setPosition);
```

This works great. Then I added an ai agent that needs to know where the player is, so I pulled player's position state up to the App level, so I could create a "findClosestPlayer" method, and pass that to my AI.

Now I want to add multiple players, and things are getting hairy...
It would be really convenient to do something like this:

```
//this would need to be wrapped in useState/useRef to avoid reevaluations every render, but let's ignore that
const playerPositions: Array<[Position2D, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Position2D>>]> = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    playerPositions.push(
      useState<Position2D>({ x: i, y: i })
    );
  }

return (
      {playerPositions.map((positionTuple) => (
        <Player
          position={positionTuple[0]}
          setPosition={positionTuple[1]}
          skin={PlayerSprite}
          positionIsWalkable={positionIsWalkable}
        />
      ))}
)
```

But you can't use useState in a loop.

I explored doing something like:

```
  const [playerPositions, setPlayerPositions] = useState<Position2D[]>([]);

  const setPlayerPosition = useCallback((playerIndex: number) => (pos: Position2D) => {
    setPlayerPositions(prev => {
      let copy = prev.slice();
      copy[playerIndex] = pos;
      return copy;
    })
  },[]);
```

But then setPlayerPosition(playerIndex) is of type (pos: Position2D) => void instead of Dispatch<SetStateEvent>, which prevents me doing stuff like setPosition(prev=> {...}) down in player && useWalk, not to mention that useWalk is expecting the Dispatch function prop, since it's used by other agents then just my player.

Any thoughts?  My ideal solution would give me a [Position2D, Dispatch<SetStateAction>] tuple per player, but I'm open to other suggestions.

My goal was to create this entirely in React as a learning objective (this is my first time working in React), but perhaps this sort of domain state management is really best left to something like Redux (which I also still need to learn). But if I could manage it, I'd love to finish this project purely in React before refactoring and incorporating something like Redux.

Answer (score 0):

At a really basic level, you could essentially map the individual player actions to work as though it's a normal setPosition function - Make it work with both the normal and function way of updating the state, just make it work for a single player at a time.

To get more complicated, but likely a better solution overall, I'd suggest to use the [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to store all of your state. That way you don't have to pass down individual states all throughout your application. You can combine that with the way this works as well - so your further down components could access the player positions via context.

You can also `useReducer` to set up the more complicated logic and actions to do what you want with the player positions, then you can pass around the dispatch.

There's also the fairly new [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) library that has the ability to do more dynamic access than redux, though it's still fairly new and I haven't yet had a chance to work with it.

```
const numPlayers = 4;
const [playerPositions, setAllPlayerPositions] = useState<Position2D[]>(() => {
  return Array(numPlayers)
    .fill(null)
    .map((_val, index) => ({ x: index, y: index }));
});
const setPlayerPositions = useMemo<
  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Position2D>>[]
>(() => {
  const setters = Array(numPlayers)
    .fill(null)
    .map<React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Position2D>>>(
      (_val, index) => (value) => {
        setAllPlayerPositions((prevValue) => {
          const newSubValue =
            typeof value === 'function' ? value(prevValue[index]) : value;
          if (newSubValue !== prevValue[index]) {
            return prevValue;
          }
          const newValue = prevValue.slice();
          newValue.splice(index, 1, newSubValue);
          return newValue;
        });
      }
    );
  return setters;
}, [numPlayers]);

return (
  <>
    {playerPositions.map((position, index) => (
      <Player
        position={position}
        setPosition={setPlayerPositions[index]}
        skin={PlayerSprite}
        positionIsWalkable={positionIsWalkable}
      />
    ))}
  </>
);
```